# Google IN-APP Billing Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I just had a weird experience. I was able to purchase a managed InApp item multiple times on the same device and same account. When I went into Google wallet it was showing all 5 charges? Worse Google Play returns the item was not purchased when the app does an inquiry. InApp was working fine when I first published it on google play. (I did testing for all scenarios)

This is InApp Billing V3

The app does not consume.

The account is not a test account

I thought multiple purchases was impossible.

Below is the data from Google wallet. They are all from the same device and account. I manual canceled so they would not be charged.

Canceled
Feb 15, 2015 11:12:18 AM
12999763169054705758.1330527826413321
Purchase (Best Weather APP & Radar)
$1.06

Canceled
Feb 15, 2015 11:09:20 AM
12999763169054705758.1307086121210892
Purchase (Best Weather APP & Radar)
$1.06

Canceled
Feb 15, 2015 11:01:18 AM
12999763169054705758.1341416031252121
Purchase (Best Weather APP & Radar)
$1.06

Canceled
Feb 15, 2015 10:56:11 AM
12999763169054705758.1367895219053448
Purchase (Best Weather APP & Radar)
$1.06

Thanks, 
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was using the incorrect LICENSE KEY from my other app. Weird part it worked fine in alpha and beta but stopped working in production. I guess google recognized it as a valid key but did not know how to process it on the wrong app. Be careful when comparing the keys they are very similar the first and last 20 characters were the same. Changes were mainly in the middle.